# Reading files in C#, differences in methods

Tags: c#, .net, file

Studying C#, my books are showing me classes for readin files. I've found 2 that are very similar and the Visual Studio debugger doesn't show an obvious difference between the two.

code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Now I wonder, what's the difference between these 2 ways of reading a file. Is there any internal difference you know of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latter is just a factory which returns an instance of `FileStream`. I.e. they do the same.

Here's the implementation for `Open()`:

```
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) {

   return new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s67691sb.aspx), you'll find they are the same.